# Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying to debug a problem for the past two days, my code, as follows, is first attempting to retrieve the category by its:

Controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $stats = [
        'done' => UserTransaction::where('status', UserTransaction::STATUS['done']),
        'canceled' => UserTransaction::where('status', UserTransaction::STATUS['canceled']),
        'waiting_payment' => UserTransaction::where('status', UserTransaction::STATUS['waiting_payment']),
    ];
    return view('admin.transaction.index', compact('stats'));
}
```

UserTransaction.php

```
const STATUS = [
    'done' => 'done',
    'canceled' => 'canceled',
    'waiting_payment' => 'waiting_payment',
];
```

index.blade.php

```
<h3 class="info">{!! $stats['done'] !!}</h3>
```

I see this error

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string (View: C:\xampp3\htdocs\projects\webafra\tessa-admin\Modules\Transaction\Resources\views\admin\index.blade.php)

Comment: UserTransaction::where('status', UserTransaction::STATUS['done']) to UserTransaction::where('status', UserTransaction::STATUS['done'])->first()

Comment: `done` is an object You will have to look deeper into it for your string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to modify your query

```
  $stats = [
        'done' => UserTransaction::where('status', UserTransaction::STATUS['done'])->first(),
        'canceled' => UserTransaction::where('status', UserTransaction::STATUS['canceled'])->first(),
        'waiting_payment' => UserTransaction::where('status', UserTransaction::STATUS['waiting_payment'])->first(),
    ];
```

also make sure `$stats['done']` return `object`.you should  fetch like `$stats['done']->status`

also you can improve your code a bit

create a scope method in your model

```
  public function scopeStatus($query,$status){
    
    $query->where('status',$status);
    
    }
```

then you can access like this

```
   UserTransaction::status(UserTransaction::STATUS['done'])->first();
```

Also you can keep status array in constant separately in config  or you have to create each scope for each status

**Updated**
Since you are looking for count of the status

```
  $stats = [
        'done' => UserTransaction::where('status', UserTransaction::STATUS['done'])->count(),
        'canceled' => UserTransaction::where('status', UserTransaction::STATUS['canceled'])->count(),
        'waiting_payment' => UserTransaction::where('status', UserTransaction::STATUS['waiting_payment'])->count(),
    ];
```

Comment: But I want to display the count().

Comment: UserTransaction::status(UserTransaction::STATUS['done'])->count();

Comment: then change first() to count();

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi.if any error let me know

Answer (score 0):

Your $stats is actually an Object of the UserTransaction query and this cannot displayed in the blade as a String.

Debug the stats Object with:

```
<h3 class="info">{!! dd($stats['done']) !!}</h3>
```

and see how the Object is displayed